# Content plugin with more than one tab in article edit view

Tags: development, joomla-3.3.x, plugin

i am making a simple content plugin using the joomla 3 docs.

However i want more than 1 tab to appear.

here are my main files. Plugin is installed an runs succesfully but only one tab will ever appear.

extras.php

```
// no direct access
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access' );
class plgContentExtras extends JPlugin {

// the language file would have to go into languages folder

        protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

        function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
                $app = JFactory::getApplication();
                $option = $app->input->get('option');
                switch($option) {
                        case 'com_content':
                                if ($app->isAdmin()) {

                                        JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                                        $form->loadFile('extras', true);

                                }                           

                                return true;
                }
                return true;
        }
}
```

forms/extras.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
        <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="params"  label="Map" >
                        <field
                                name="mapinfo"
                                type="text"
                                label="Map Info"
                                />

                </fieldset>

                <fieldset name="params"  label="eBlast" >
                        <field
                                name="eblastinfo"
                                type="text"
                                label="Eblast Info"
                                />

                </fieldset>

        </fields>   

</form>
```

Thanks to anyone in advance for your help :)

ps: i am a novice to this.

I did also try adding an extra `$form->loadFile('eblast', true);` to the extras.php file and then creating an extra file called **eblast.xml** within the **forms/** folder but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have assigned the same name to both `<fieldset>` tags. Each one must have a different name, for example:

```
<fieldset name="map" label="Map">
    <field
        name="mapinfo"
        type="text"
        label="Map Info"
    />
</fieldset>

<fieldset name="eblast" label="eBlast">
    <field
        name="eblastinfo"
        type="text"
        label="Eblast Info"
    />
</fieldset>
```

You will see I've used `name="map"` and `name="eblast"`.

#### Update:

To access the parameters, you can simply use the following:

```
$this->params->get('mapinfo');
$this->params->get('eblastinfo');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh @Lodder You little beauty! it worked. Such a little thing that i would never have guessed as im working backwards with this stuff. Meaning my knowledge is in snippets as i need to know rather than geekified braniac code freak like some people i encounter online when asking a 'nube' question.Im guessing that retrieving those values will be ->map->mapinfo etc... Ill check, but thank you so much!!! - once i have checked ill come back and mark you correct and add an update to my question yes? Maybe you can help me with my other question about 'Custom Component 3 levels deep' components :)

Comment: @Jonnypixel - Glad it helped ;) I've updated my answer with how to access the parameter. It appears you have already accepted the answer for your other question.

Comment: Thankyou again - yes i did accept it but only because it made sense. Should i unaccept it in order fro you to help out there? is that what you mean? Also i just realized that i think params wont work. The content table has attribs. Testing now

Comment: No, do not unaccept it unless someone provides you with a solid answer to your question. I will take a look tomorrow but you may want to comment below the current answer and ask for more detail ;)

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks Lodder. I will go back to it and ask more. I think i didi ask him to elaborate more on the FoF thing. Because i think he did point me the right way. I just dont quite understand how t implement it.